# Why can't I install OS X Snow Leopard v10.6.2 from disc on my computer that has OS X v10.5.8?

Tags: macos, mac, installation, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade

When I go to install it says "Can't install on this computer".

Comment: Use System Profiler / System Information to see which exact model you have and report back. It'll be something like "iMacX,Y". Also, is this a retail kit or were these discs that came with a different model of Mac?

Comment: Imac7,1  says System Profiler

Comment: Just bought off ebay.  Looks the ones I got when I bought my mac. 2 Discs  Install DVD and Applications Install DVD    Thanks Spiff

Comment: When I tried other Install Options it said I needed OS 10.6 or higher.  Am I screwed having 10.5.8      I guess?

Comment: A friend said I may be able to Clean Install the 10.6.2    Said you can back up all my files.  Is this possible and right?  Something about holding C key down when mac is shut down and turned back on?  I'm a computer moron.  Thanks.

Comment: IIRC the two-disk sets are the versions shipped in-box with new Macs, and won't work on anything except the specific model they shipped with (see @Spiff's comment). Also, I don't think 10.6.2 shipped as a universal installer, only in model-specific discs. I *think* 10.6.0 and 10.6.3 are the only ones shipped as universal installers (although there are also model-specific discs of those versions as well).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like someone sold you the discs that came with their Mac, not a retail upgrade kit like you can buy for USD$20 [here](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard). The install discs that come with a given model of Mac often include software that was bundled with the Mac, not just a standard OS install. Because of that, they are locked to only install on the Mac model they came with.

By the way, your iMac7,1 (mid-2007), given enough RAM, can run OS X 10.11 El Capitan, which comes out Tuesday (Sept 30th 2015), and is free. But yes, you have to get it to Snow Leopard before the El Capitan installer will run, so you'll probably have to pay the $20 for a real Snow Leopard retail kit.